# Asymptotic distribution of an estimator

Tags: estimation, asymptotics

I have the following problem:

Let $X_1,..., X_n$ be a sample of independent, identically distributed random variables, with density $$f_{\theta}(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{\theta-x}, & \text{if } x\geq \theta\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{cases}$$

Let $\hat\theta_n$ be the maximum-likelihood estimator (MLE) of $\theta$. I am asked to find the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt n (\hat\theta_n-\theta)$ and $\hat\theta_n$ efficiency. I will have to prove later that the asymptotic distribution of $ n(\hat\theta_n-\theta)$ is $Exp(1)$, but if I have the first part I think I will able to figure it out.

So far, I computed the MLE, which is $\hat\theta_n=min\{x_i\}$, for $i=0,...,n.$, and the pdf of this MLE is $ne^{n(\theta-x)}$.

Any hints or solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you have the PDF of $\hat\theta_n,$ you can (easily) find its CDF and then (just as easily) express the CDF of $\sqrt{n}(\hat\theta_n-\theta).$ Do that and take the limit as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: Also cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404365/determine-asymptotic-distribution-and-efficiency-of-an-estimator/. I don't quite agree with the accepted answer in the linked 'duplicate' post.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

This is a shifted exponential distribution with rate $\lambda = 1$ and support $[\theta, \infty).$
You already know that the minimum observation $X_{1:n}$ in a sample
sample of size $n$ is the MLE. Because the minimum is always greater than $\theta$ the MLE is also biased. Furthermore, the the minimum is a shifted
exponential with rate $n\lambda$ and $E(X_{1:n}) = \theta + \frac{1}{n\lambda}.$

As $n$ increases, the bias decreases. The exponential rate increases, so
that the distribution of the minimum converges to the point $\theta.$
I am not sure what discussion of efficiency you plan to include.

Below (from R) is the simulated distribution of $\hat\theta$ for $\theta = 2$ and
$n = 10$ observations.

```
set.seed(1022);  n = 10;  th = 2
est.th = replicate(10^6, min(rexp(n) + th) )
mean(est.th);  sd(est.th)
[1] 2.099804     # aprx 2 + 1/n = 2.1
[1] 0.09993662   # aprx 1/n = 0.1 
mse = mean((est.th - th)^2);  mse
[1] 0.01994817   # aprx Var(est.th)+bias^2(est.th) = .01+.01=.02

uest.th = est.th-1/n    # unbiased estimate
mean(uest.th)
[1] 1.999804            # aprx th = 2
mse.u = mean((uest.th - th)^2);  mse.u
[1] 0.009987356         

hist(est.th, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dexp(x - th, n), add=T, col="red")
```

[image]